What can I use to make informational popups shortly after boot on Linux Mint?
I work with seniors, and many of them have expressed interest in learning more about their computers.  Looking for a way to make an informational pop-up that changes each time the customer starts, I was thinking a zenity script, but don't know how to find out how to make them rotate, also want the user to be able to turn them off.
Any help will help educate thousands of people.

Great idea, and it appears others have thought of that, too: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-a-custom-message-of-the-day-on-linux and https://serversforhackers.com/c/customize-your-login-screen-via-linuxs-message-of-the-day-ubuntucentos might be of help.

Go with yad.  It's a zenity fork with lots of extra features.
